# how to create a DAL using petapoco

Tags: petapoco

I need to create a DAL and repositories using petapoco. The difficulty that comes in, is that I dont know how it manages its connections.

If I was using dapper I know how the connection process flows because I control it. I don't know what are the best practices in creating a DAL with petapoco.

```
 public class UserRepository
    {
        public IEnumerable<User> All()
        {
            var db = new PetaPoco.Database("Sqlite_Connection");//this line
            var s = db.Query<User>("SELECT * FROM Users");
            return s.ToList();
        }
    }
```

I would like to place `var db = new PetaPoco.Database("Sqlite_Connection");//this line`
in my DALHelper class as a static property but I'm worried about scalability

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I don't recommend using a static since you can get errors like ["There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command"](https://github.com/toptensoftware/PetaPoco/issues/103) because the same connection is used by different request accesing the same resource.

Two options:

## 1. Create the connection in a controller base class

```
public class BaseController : Controller 
{
  protected DatabaseWithMVCMiniProfiler _database;

  protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterCon ) 
  {
    base.OnActionExecuting( filterCon );

    _database = new DatabaseWithMVCMiniProfiler( "MainConnectionString");

  }
}
```

## 2. Static method creating one connection per request

```
public static class DbHelper {
  public static Database CurrentDb() {
    if (HttpContext.Current.Items["CurrentDb"] == null) {
       var retval = new DatabaseWithMVCMiniProfiler("MainConnectionString");
       HttpContext.Current.Items["CurrentDb"] = retval;
       return retval;
    }
    return (Database)HttpContext.Current.Items["CurrentDb"];
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Eduardo, makes me confident with PetaPoco again, also just found this SO with suggestion to use 1 petapoco.database instance per request: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7126205/how-can-integrate-mvcminiprofiler-with-petapoco-without-changing-the-sources

Comment: PetaPoco is fabulous. I'm using it in several projects now and works very well in all kinds of scenarios.

Answer (score 3):

A static property will be fine for the Initialization. 
PetaPoco will open and close the connection each time, unless you are using a transaction. This isn't usually an issue due to connection pooling.

If you are using this in a web application then you should instantiate one PetaPoco database per request.

Comment: I am using it this way in production to handle nested transaction between DAL operations and it is working fine.

Comment: I (and others) have found that using a static (as in per application) have problems. See my answer.