# PetaPoco KeepConnectionAlive use

Tags: c#, asp.net, petapoco

I am fetching my Database object in PetaPoco using this method:

```
internal static Database GetCurrentDatabase()
    {
        if (HttpContext.Current == null)
        {
            if (Thread.GetData(Thread.GetNamedDataSlot(_databaseKey)) != null)
                return Thread.GetData(Thread.GetNamedDataSlot(_databaseKey)) as Database;
            else
            {

                var database = new Database("testDB");
                database.KeepConnectionAlive = true;
                database.EnableAutoSelect = true;
                database.CommandTimeout = 180;
                Thread.SetData(Thread.GetNamedDataSlot(_databaseKey), database);
                return database;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (HttpContext.Current.Items.Contains(_databaseKey))
                return HttpContext.Current.Items[_databaseKey] as Database;
            else
            {
                Database database = new Database("testDB");
                database.EnableAutoSelect = true;
                database.CommandTimeout = 180;
                database.KeepConnectionAlive = true;
                HttpContext.Current.Items[_databaseKey] = database;
                return database;
            }
        }
    }
```

My connection string in web.config:

```
<add name="testDB" connectionString="Data Source=192.168.10.10;Initial Catalog=testDB;User Id=test;Password=test;pooling='true'; Max Pool Size=200"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Question is already connection pooling is enabled. Do I have to set `KeepConnectionAlive` as true or false? What is the use of this property?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, pooling is already enable and you don't need to set KeepConnectionAlive to true (in fact, it will bring trouble if you set it to true)

Comment: Sorry, what kind of trouble is it?

Comment: Like getting errors for sharing the same Conn for the same record set

Comment: Sorry could you explain what do you mean by that? I have turned it off already but I need to understand what your valuable comments mean.

Comment: If you let your connection open for more than one request or thread and you try to access the same set of records (the same query) in different request or threads, PetaPoco, (in fact ADO.net, the library behind PetaPoco) will error out. See https://github.com/CollaboratingPlatypus/PetaPoco/issues/103 or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7052350/how-to-create-a-dal-using-petapoco/9995413 for more info