# Petapoco with factory design pattern for multiple server connections

Tags: design-patterns, petapoco

How can we use multiple connections in petaPOCO with  .net MVC application using factory design pattern?

Answer (score 1):

There's no problem using a factory pattern, but only use one PetaPoco DB per request.

You can use more than one per request, but you are creating more connections to the DB, having performance costs.

See this answer for more info [how to create a DAL using petapoco](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7052350/how-to-create-a-dal-using-petapoco/9995413)